# Google admin SDK custom scheme issue

Tags: php, google-admin-sdk

I need help on custom scheme on Google.
I successfully get the user list from delegation.
Below is my code.

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('xx');
$scopes = array('www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user','www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.userschema');
$client->setAuthConfig('C:\Users\xx\xx\public\client_secret.json');
$client->setScopes($scopes);
$user_to_impersonate = 'xx.sg';
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);

$dir = new \Google_Service_Directory($client);
$r = $dir->users->get('xxx@xx.com');
dd($r);
```

Userscheme have been added to Google also.

But the custom scheme I got is empty.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JcfZ.png

If I use projection = full in developers.google.com/admin it works.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s3MQ.png

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-schemas) says:

> You can fetch custom fields in a user profile by setting the `projection` parameter in a `users.get` or `users.list` request to `custom` or `full`.

so I would replace your line:

```
$r = $dir->users->get('xxx@xx.sg');
```

with:

```
$optParams = array('projection' => 'full');
$r = $dir->users->get('xxx@xx.sg', $optParams);
```

Comment: thanks peter. This is work. Hope you have a great day.